# Yii2 -Dyanamic Page

Tags: php, yii2

[image][image]Here I want to save dynamic page data into database.There vendors controller I display list data from two different controller as per dependency and save into 3rd table with vendors created id with dynamic form contain i.e After selecting main category our sub category will be change that is dynamic.But after clicking on create button it return back to create form I think else condition executed. but I can't understand how and why.Please help me I am stuck from last 2 with this.I am follow below link for this dynamic form Thanks in advance.
I have attach page for more understanding
https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform

```
    $model = new Vendors();//main controller In this controller i have save data dynamically 


    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) { 

         $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = Model::createMultiple(VendorsMoreCategories::classname());
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsVendorsMoreCategories, Yii::$app->request->post());

        $valid = $modelsBusinessMainCategories->validate();
        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsBusinessSubCategories) && $valid;

        if ($valid) {

            $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                    foreach ($modelsVendorsMoreCategories as $modelVendorsMoreCategories) {
                        $modelVendorsMoreCategories->vmc_ven_id = $model->ven_id;
                        if (!($flag = $modelVendorsMoreCategories->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ven_id]);
                   }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        } 
}else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsBusinessSubCategories' => (empty($modelsBusinessSubCategories)) ? [new BusinessSubCategories] : $modelsBusinessSubCategories

            ]);
        }
```

Now it work properly here in vendor controller I have do dynamic registration for one id.After creating vendor id as per dynamic form selection.Dynamic record created into "**vendor-more-ategory**" table with vendors table vendor id and dynamic selection of main category & it's sub category

```
 <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($modelVendorsMoreCategories, "[{$i}]vmc_bmc_id")->dropDownList(                                               ArrayHelper::map(BusinessMainCategories::find()->all(), 'bmc_id', 'bmc_name'),
        ['prompt' => 'Select Main Category','onchange'=>' $.post("index.php?r=business-sub-categories/lists&id=' . '"+$(this).val(),function(data){                                               $("select#vendorsmorecategories-'.$i.'-vmc_bsc_id").html(data);
});']);//Here I want to increment id but it still 0 for all selection
?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<?= $form->field($modelVendorsMoreCategories, "[{$i}]vmc_bsc_id")->dropDownList(
                                                    ArrayHelper::map(BusinessSubCategories::find()->all(), 'bsc_id', 'bsc_name'),
     [
      'prompt' => 'Select Sub Category'
     ]);?>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think because `&& $model->save()` is not getting executed in `if(...)`. Bye the way, Where is @Scais Edge And @Insane Skull? I think they may have answer.

Comment: Thnaks,I have remove $model->save() from this action and it will save properly into database....But tell one more think...

Comment: But I stuck with one dependency drop down selection problem...I will attach Image it helps you to understand

Comment: I have attached image and patch java script code I think I have to increment onChange selection list id but I am not able to do this.-Please help...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
          <?=
             $this->registerJs('
             window.hideButton=(function(e){
             $(e).hide();
            })
           $(document).ready(function(){ 
              $(".add-item").click(function(){
                  $(this).hide();
         });                                        
      });', \yii\web\View::POS_READY);


    echo $form->field($modelVendorsMoreCategories, "[{$i}]bmc_id")->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(BusinessMainCategories::find()->where(['deleted' => 'N'])
    ->andwhere(['<>','bmc_name',strtolower(trim('Live Event'))])->all(), 'bmc_id', 'bmc_name'),
    ['prompt' => 'Select Main Category',
    'onchange' => 'var valint=this.id;
     var finVal=valint.replace("bmc_id", "bsc_id");


    $.post("index.php?r=business-sub-categories/lists&id=' . '"+$(this).val(),function(data){
    $("select#"+finVal).html(data);
     });']);


    ?>
   </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" id="c">

     <?= $form->field($modelVendorsMoreCategories, "[{$i}]bsc_id")->dropDownList(                                                                     ArrayHelper::map(BusinessSubCategories::find()->all(), 'bsc_id', 'bsc_name'),
    'prompt' => 'Select Sub Category'
     ]);

 ?>
</div>
</div><!-- .row -->
```